# Why margin top does not work in Tailwind CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to top margin `mt-10` in `first` but it is not working. However, if I give that expression as `mx-10`- it is working.

```
<div className="font-bold text-white">
  <a id='first' className="mt-10">Explore</a>
  <a id='second' className="mx-4">Collections</a>
  <a id='third' className="mx-4">Profiles</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Sometimes there are issues with top margins collapsing with the bottom margin of the element above. You could instead try adding padding to your wrapper `<div>`, e.g. `pt-10`.

Answer (score 6):

When it comes to margins and padding, browsers treat inline elements differently. You can add space to the left and right on an inline element, but you cannot add height to the top or bottom padding or margin of an inline element. Give the `<a>` tags an `inline-block` class to solve this problem.

```html
<div className="font-bold text-white">
  <a id='first' className="mt-10 inline-block">Explore</a>
  <a id='second' className="mx-4 inline-block">Collections</a>
  <a id='third' className="mx-4 inline-block">Profiles</a>
</div>
```

Related Links: [Margin Properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties)